# How to build a random button picker with the blocks in app inventor 2?

Tags: android, smartphone, app-inventor

I am a beginner and I don’t have any experience with coding etc. and I need help

The first screenshot:

[image]

shows my screen, and as you can depict from it there are two buttons- the first one is called RIGHT BUTTON, and the other one is called WRONG BUTTON. This is because clicking on the RIGHT BUTTON will open a next screen, whereas clicking on the WRONG BUTTON will result in going back to the previous screen. I thought that this is kind of boring :D that’s why I want to build something with the blocks that would choose randomly one of those buttons to be right and the other one to be wrong after the screen has initialized. To make it more clear. Every time I start the app I don’t know which button out of those two will take me one screen further- it could be the first or the second button- I want this to be a random pick.

Now, I have tried to build something like this blocks:

[image]

but I can’t find a suitable block, as you can see in screen shot 2 :D I assume, that this isn’t the way it should look like, but my skill is too low at the moment. I also assume that I will need an "if,then" block" I would be really grateful if someone built it and made a screenshot and post it here ;)

Basically, I am kindly asking for help. I have been looking on the internet for a tutorial etc. but I couldn’t find something that would really help me.

Thank you very much in advance ;)

Comment: A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles  
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Comment: see the answers in [your forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/h5ANgS9tknY/5g_blVOxBwAJ)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here this is the answer I have found for my problem using your info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EPAr.png)

[image: GUI solution]

Answer (score 1):

When the button is pressed, instead of opening the next/prev screen, instead call a custom procedure and have that procedure decide if it was the right button to press or not. This can be done several ways, for instance with the Math.randomInteger block. You don't actually have to decide if it was the right button or not before the button is pressed, just do a "coin flip" at the time of the button press to decide (at least that's what it sounds like you wanted from your description).

Also note that the number of screens in AI is highly limited, and instead of going to another screen, you can just reuse the same buttons over and over (and maybe just show a label in the corner counting how far you've come), or make lots of buttons and only have the first two visible at the start, then as you progress hide/unhide the correct buttons.